# Saving a form to a database

Tags: c#, sql, form

I have a windows form application which uses a form for two different purposes. We use the form for both our handheld system and our in-house system.

I would just like someone to review the code for saving and see if I have done it the best way or if not, what the best solution is.

**Windows Form Save Method**

```
private void SavePDVDetails()
    {
        LockType = 0;
        AccessInfo = 0;
        V2a = 0;
        V10a = 0;
        PayMethod = 0;

        SaveCheckBoxes(ref LockType, ref AccessInfo, ref V2a, ref V10a, ref PayMethod);

        var pdv = isHandheld == true ? new PDVHH() : new PDV();

        if (!isHandheld)
            pdv.Timestamp = timestamp;

        pdv.CaseID = caseID;
        pdv.CustContactTel = txtCustContactTel.Text;
        pdv.CustMobileTel = txtCustMobileTel.Text;
        pdv.PropertyType = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboPropertyType);
        pdv.PremisesStatus = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboPremisesStatus);
        pdv.LockType = LockType;
        pdv.AccessInfo = AccessInfo;
        pdv.V1 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV1);
        pdv.V2 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV2);
        pdv.V2a = V2a;
        pdv.V3 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV3);
        pdv.V4 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV4);
        pdv.V4a = txtV4a.Text;
        pdv.V5 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV5);
        pdv.V6 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV6);
        pdv.V7 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV7);
        pdv.V7a = txtV7a.Text;
        pdv.V8 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV8);
        pdv.V8a = txtV8a.Text;
        pdv.V9 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV9);
        pdv.V9a = txtV9a.Text;
        pdv.V10 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV10);
        pdv.V10a = V10a;
        pdv.V11 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV11);
        pdv.V11a = txtV11a.Text;
        pdv.V12 = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboV12);
        pdv.VulnerableOther = txtVulnerableOther.Text;
        pdv.ContactType = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboContactType);
        pdv.NINumber = txtNINumber.Text;
        pdv.ContactDate = mtxtContactDate.Text;
        pdv.CustDOB = mtxtCustDOB.Text;
        pdv.PayAmount = txtPayAmount.Text == string.Empty ? Convert.ToDouble(null) : Convert.ToDouble(txtPayAmount.Text);
        pdv.ClearedFunds = chkClearedFunds.Checked;
        pdv.PayAmount2 = txtPayAmount2.Text == string.Empty ? Convert.ToDouble(null) : Convert.ToDouble(txtPayAmount2.Text);
        pdv.ClearedFunds2 = chkClearedFunds.Checked;
        pdv.PayMethod = PayMethod;
        pdv.ReceiptNo = txtReceiptNo.Text;
        pdv.DirectPayAmount = txtDirectPayAmount.Text == string.Empty ? Convert.ToDouble(null) : Convert.ToDouble(txtDirectPayAmount.Text);
        pdv.COT = chkCOT.Checked;
        pdv.TitleCode = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboTitle);
        pdv.OtherTitle = txtOtherTitle.Text;
        pdv.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        pdv.MiddleInitials = txtMiddleInitials.Text;
        pdv.SurName = txtSurName.Text;
        pdv.COTProofType = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboCOTProofType);
        pdv.COTDate = mtxtCOTDate.Text;
        pdv.PropRespMtrRead = txtPropRestMtrRead.Text;
        pdv.PropRespMtrBRead = txtPropRestMtrBRead.Text;
        pdv.PrevAdd1 = txtPrevAdd1.Text;
        pdv.PrevAdd2 = txtPrevAdd2.Text;
        pdv.PrevAdd3 = txtPrevAdd3.Text;
        pdv.PrevAdd4 = txtPrevAdd4.Text;
        pdv.PrevPostcode = txtPrevAddPostcode.Text;
        pdv.FwdName = txtFwdName.Text;
        pdv.FwdAdd1 = txtFwdAdd1.Text;
        pdv.FwdAdd2 = txtFwdAdd2.Text;
        pdv.FwdAdd3 = txtFwdAdd3.Text;
        pdv.FwdAdd4 = txtFwdAdd4.Text;
        pdv.FwdPostcode = txtFwdAddPostcode.Text;
        pdv.PayArranged = chkPayArranged.Checked;
        pdv.PayStartDate = mtxtPayStartDate.Text;
        pdv.PayArrAmount = txtPayArrAmount.Text == string.Empty ? Convert.ToDouble(null) : Convert.ToDouble(txtPayArrAmount.Text);
        pdv.Frequency = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboFrequency);
        pdv.PayArrDetail = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboPayArrDetail);
        pdv.PPMAgreed = chkPPMAgreed.Checked;
        pdv.PPMBookedDate = mtxtPPMApptDate.Text;
        pdv.PPMHHBookedTime = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboPPMApptTime);
        pdv.EmploymentStatus = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboEmploymentStatus);
        pdv.RecoveryRate = txtRecoveryRate.Text == string.Empty ? Convert.ToDouble(null) : Convert.ToDouble(txtRecoveryRate.Text);
        pdv.PPMApptComments = txtPPMApptComments.Text;
        pdv.PPMArranged = chkPPMArranged.Checked;
        pdv.PPMAppointmentDate = mtxtPPMAppointmentDate.Text;
        pdv.PPMDetail = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboPPMDetail);
        pdv.AuthCode = txtAuthCode.Text;
        pdv.DateOfLeaving = mtxtDateOfLeaving.Text;
        pdv.VacantPropComments = txtVacPropComments.Text;
        pdv.CustComplaintCode = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboCustComplaintCode);
        pdv.DisputeComments = txtDisputeComments.Text;
        pdv.IncidentDets = txtIncidentDets.Text;
        pdv.PDVComments = txtPDVComments.Text;
        pdv.Dissatisfaction = chkDissatisfied.Checked;
        pdv.DissatisfactionComments = txtDissatisfiedComments.Text;
        pdv.HealthSafety = chkHealthSafety.Checked;
        pdv.ContactCode = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboContact_Code);
        pdv.WhoSpokenTo = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboWhoSpokenTo);
        pdv.HealthSafetyComments = txtHealthSafetyComments.Text;
        pdv.InfoNotes = txtInfoNotes.Text;
        pdv.EnergyTrust = chkEnergyTrust.Checked;
        pdv.EnergyTrustComments = txtEnergyTrustComments.Text;
        pdv.VisitDate1 = mtxtVisitDate1.Text;
        pdv.VisitTime = mtxtVisitTime.Text;
        pdv.VisitDate2 = mtxtVisitDate2.Text;
        pdv.VisitTime2 = mtxtVisitTime2.Text;

        if (isHandheld)
        {
            (pdv as PDVHH).PDVResult = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboGasPDVResult);
            (pdv as PDVHH).SecPDVResult = Systems.CheckComboNullString(cboElectricPDVResult);
            pdvDetails.SavePDVHH((PDVHH)pdv);
        }
        else
            pdvDetails.SavePDV(pdv);

        UpdateMeterPDV();

        AccountDetails.SaveMeterPDV(meterPDV, isHandheld);
    }
```

**Model**

```
   public class PDV
{
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
    public object Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string CustContactTel { get; set; }
    public string CustMobileTel { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string PremisesStatus { get; set; }
    public int LockType { get; set; }
    public int AccessInfo { get; set; }
    public string V1 { get; set; }
    public string V2 { get; set; }
    public int V2a { get; set; }
    public string V3 { get; set; }
    public string V4 { get; set; }
    public string V4a { get; set; }
    public string V5 { get; set; }
    public string V6 { get; set; }
    public string V7 { get; set; }
    public string V7a { get; set; }
    public string V8 { get; set; }
    public string V8a { get; set; }
    public string V9 { get; set; }
    public string V9a { get; set; }
    public string V10 { get; set; }
    public int V10a { get; set; }
    public string V11 { get; set; }
    public string V11a { get; set; }
    public string V12 { get; set; }
    public string VulnerableOther { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string NINumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactDate { get; set; }
    public string CustDOB { get; set; }
    public double? PayAmount { get; set; }
    public bool ClearedFunds { get; set; }
    public double? PayAmount2 { get; set; }
    public bool ClearedFunds2 { get; set; }
    public int PayMethod { get; set; }
    public string ReceiptNo { get; set; }
    public double? DirectPayAmount { get; set; }
    public bool COT { get; set; }
    public string TitleCode { get; set; }
    public string OtherTitle { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitials { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string COTProofType { get; set; }
    public string COTDate { get; set; }
    public string PropRespMtrRead { get; set; }
    public string PropRespMtrBRead { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd1 { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd2 { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd3 { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd4 { get; set; }
    public string PrevPostcode { get; set; }
    public string FwdName { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd1 { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd2 { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd3 { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd4 { get; set; }
    public string FwdPostcode { get; set; }
    public bool PayArranged { get; set; }
    public string PayStartDate { get; set; }
    public double? PayArrAmount { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public string PayArrDetail { get; set; }
    public bool PPMAgreed { get; set; }
    public string PPMBookedDate { get; set; }
    public string PPMHHBookedTime { get; set; }
    public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
    public double? RecoveryRate { get; set; }
    public string PPMApptComments { get; set; }
    public bool PPMArranged { get; set; }
    public string PPMAppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public string PPMDetail { get; set; }
    public string AuthCode { get; set; }
    public string DateOfLeaving { get; set; }
    public string VacantPropComments { get; set; }
    public string CustComplaintCode { get; set; }
    public string DisputeComments { get; set; }
    public string IncidentDets { get; set; }
    public string PDVComments { get; set; }
    public bool Dissatisfaction { get; set; }
    public string DissatisfactionComments { get; set; }
    public bool HealthSafety { get; set; }
    public string ContactCode { get; set; }
    public string WhoSpokenTo { get; set; }
    public string HealthSafetyComments { get; set; }
    public string InfoNotes { get; set; }
    public bool EnergyTrust { get; set; }
    public string EnergyTrustComments { get; set; }
    public string VisitDate1 { get; set; }
    public string VisitTime { get; set; }
    public string VisitDate2 { get; set; }
    public string VisitTime2 { get; set; }
    public string ClientComments { get; set; }
    public string PDVNote { get; set; }
}

public class PDVHH : PDV
{
    public string PDVResult { get; set; }
    public string SecPDVResult { get; set; }
    public string D2PrintDate { get; set; }
    public string RPDVResult { get; set; }
    public string RSecPDVResult { get; set; }
}
```

**Save Functions**

```
public void SavePDV(PDV pdv)
    {
        var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CaseID", pdv.CaseID));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PDVTimestamp", pdv.Timestamp));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustContactTel", pdv.CustContactTel));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustMobileTel",pdv.CustMobileTel));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PropertyType", pdv.PropertyType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PremisesStatus", pdv.PremisesStatus));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockType", pdv.LockType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccessInfo", pdv.AccessInfo));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V1", pdv.V1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V2", pdv.V2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V2a", pdv.V2a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V3", pdv.V3));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V4", pdv.V4));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V4a", pdv.V4a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V5", pdv.V5));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V6", pdv.V6));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V7", pdv.V7));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("V7a", pdv.V7a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V8", pdv.V8));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V8a", pdv.V8a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V9", pdv.V9));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V9a", pdv.V9a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V10", pdv.V10));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V10a", pdv.V10a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V11", pdv.V11));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V11a", pdv.V11a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V12", pdv.V12));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VulnerableOther", pdv.VulnerableOther));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContactType", pdv.ContactType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NINumber", pdv.NINumber));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustDOB", pdv.ContactDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContactDate", pdv.CustDOB));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayAmount", pdv.PayAmount));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClearedFunds", pdv.ClearedFunds));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayAmount2", pdv.PayAmount2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClearedFunds2", pdv.ClearedFunds2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayMethod", pdv.PayMethod));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReceiptNo", pdv.ReceiptNo));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DirectPayAmount", pdv.DirectPayAmount));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@COT", pdv.COT));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TitleCode", pdv.TitleCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OtherTitle", pdv.OtherTitle));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", pdv.FirstName));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MiddleInitials", pdv.MiddleInitials));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SurName", pdv.SurName));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@COTProofType", pdv.COTProofType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@COTDate", pdv.COTDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PropRespMtrRead", pdv.PropRespMtrRead));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PropRespMtrBRead", pdv.PropRespMtrBRead));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd1", pdv.PrevAdd1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd2", pdv.PrevAdd2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd3", pdv.PrevAdd3));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd4", pdv.PrevAdd4));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevPostcode", pdv.PrevPostcode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdName", pdv.FwdName));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd1", pdv.FwdAdd1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd2", pdv.FwdAdd2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd3", pdv.FwdAdd3));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd4", pdv.FwdAdd4));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdPostcode", pdv.FwdPostcode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayArranged", pdv.PayArranged));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayStartDate", pdv.PayStartDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayArrAmount", pdv.PayArrAmount));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Frequency", pdv.Frequency));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayArrDetail", pdv.PayArrDetail));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMAgreed", pdv.PPMAgreed));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMBookedDate", pdv.PPMBookedDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMHHBookedTime", pdv.PPMHHBookedTime));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmploymentStatus", pdv.EmploymentStatus));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RecoveryRate", pdv.RecoveryRate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMApptComments", pdv.PPMApptComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMArranged", pdv.PPMArranged));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMAppointmentDate", pdv.PPMAppointmentDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMDetail", pdv.PPMDetail));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AuthCode", pdv.AuthCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfLeaving", pdv.DateOfLeaving));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VacantPropComments", pdv.VacantPropComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustComplaintCode", pdv.CustComplaintCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DisputeComments", pdv.DisputeComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncidentDets", pdv.IncidentDets));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PDVComments", pdv.PDVComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dissatisfaction", pdv.Dissatisfaction));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DissatisfactionComments", pdv.DissatisfactionComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HealthSafety", pdv.HealthSafety));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Contact_Code", pdv.ContactCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WhoSpokenTo", pdv.WhoSpokenTo));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HealthSafetyComments", pdv.HealthSafetyComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InfoNotes", pdv.InfoNotes));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnergyTrust", pdv.EnergyTrust));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnergyTrustComments", pdv.EnergyTrustComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitDate1", pdv.VisitDate1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitTime", pdv.VisitTime));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitDate2", pdv.VisitDate2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitTime2", pdv.VisitTime2));

        SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("prcUMUpdateDebtPDVDetails", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);

        parameters = null;
    }

    public void SavePDVHH(PDVHH pdv)
    {
        var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CaseID", pdv.CaseID));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustContactTel", pdv.CustContactTel));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustMobileTel", pdv.CustMobileTel));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PropertyType", pdv.PropertyType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PremisesStatus", pdv.PremisesStatus));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockType", pdv.LockType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccessInfo", pdv.AccessInfo));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V1", pdv.V1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V2", pdv.V2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V2a", pdv.V2a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V3", pdv.V3));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V4", pdv.V4));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V4a", pdv.V4a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V5", pdv.V5));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V6", pdv.V6));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V7", pdv.V7));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("V7a", pdv.V7a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V8", pdv.V8));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V8a", pdv.V8a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V9", pdv.V9));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V9a", pdv.V9a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V10", pdv.V10));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V10a", pdv.V10a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V11", pdv.V11));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V11a", pdv.V11a));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@V12", pdv.V12));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VulnerableOther", pdv.VulnerableOther));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContactType", pdv.ContactType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NINumber", pdv.NINumber));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustDOB", pdv.ContactDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContactDate", pdv.CustDOB));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayAmount", pdv.PayAmount));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayAmount2", pdv.PayAmount2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayMethod", pdv.PayMethod));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReceiptNo", pdv.ReceiptNo));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DirectPayAmount", pdv.DirectPayAmount));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@COT", pdv.COT));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TitleCode", pdv.TitleCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OtherTitle", pdv.OtherTitle));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", pdv.FirstName));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MiddleInitials", pdv.MiddleInitials));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SurName", pdv.SurName));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@COTProofType", pdv.COTProofType));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@COTDate", pdv.COTDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PropRespMtrRead", pdv.PropRespMtrRead));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PropRespMtrBRead", pdv.PropRespMtrBRead));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd1", pdv.PrevAdd1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd2", pdv.PrevAdd2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd3", pdv.PrevAdd3));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd4", pdv.PrevAdd4));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrevPostcode", pdv.PrevPostcode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdName", pdv.FwdName));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd1", pdv.FwdAdd1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd2", pdv.FwdAdd2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd3", pdv.FwdAdd3));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd4", pdv.FwdAdd4));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FwdPostcode", pdv.FwdPostcode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayArranged", pdv.PayArranged));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayStartDate", pdv.PayStartDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayArrAmount", pdv.PayArrAmount));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Frequency", pdv.Frequency));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PayArrDetail", pdv.PayArrDetail));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMAgreed", pdv.PPMAgreed));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMBookedDate", pdv.PPMBookedDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMHHBookedTime", pdv.PPMHHBookedTime));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmploymentStatus", pdv.EmploymentStatus));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RecoveryRate", pdv.RecoveryRate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMApptComments", pdv.PPMApptComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMArranged", pdv.PPMArranged));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMAppointmentDate", pdv.PPMAppointmentDate));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PPMDetail", pdv.PPMDetail));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AuthCode", pdv.AuthCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfLeaving", pdv.DateOfLeaving));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VacantPropComments", pdv.VacantPropComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustComplaintCode", pdv.CustComplaintCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DisputeComments", pdv.DisputeComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IncidentDets", pdv.IncidentDets));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PDVComments", pdv.PDVComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dissatisfaction", pdv.Dissatisfaction));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DissatisfactionComments", pdv.DissatisfactionComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HealthSafety", pdv.HealthSafety));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Contact_Code", pdv.ContactCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WhoSpokenTo", pdv.WhoSpokenTo));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HealthSafetyComments", pdv.HealthSafetyComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InfoNotes", pdv.InfoNotes));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnergyTrust", pdv.EnergyTrust));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EnergyTrustComments", pdv.EnergyTrustComments));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitDate1", pdv.VisitDate1));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitTime", pdv.VisitTime));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitDate2", pdv.VisitDate2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VisitTime2", pdv.VisitTime2));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RPDVResult", pdv.RPDVResult));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RSecPDVResult", pdv.RSecPDVResult));

        SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("prcUMUpdateDebtPDVHHDetails", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);

        parameters = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you have a lot of duplicated properties here.

What you want to do is have each of your objects maintain the list of properties that they will use during a save.

Use inheritance to your advantage. I've added a method `GetCommandParameters` to your base class, this is overridable. Its only concern is to add the parameters that are valid for that object.

```
public class PDV
{
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
    public object Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string CustContactTel { get; set; }
    public string CustMobileTel { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string PremisesStatus { get; set; }
    public int LockType { get; set; }
    public int AccessInfo { get; set; }
    public string V1 { get; set; }
    public string V2 { get; set; }
    public int V2a { get; set; }
    public string V3 { get; set; }
    public string V4 { get; set; }
    public string V4a { get; set; }
    public string V5 { get; set; }
    public string V6 { get; set; }
    public string V7 { get; set; }
    public string V7a { get; set; }
    public string V8 { get; set; }
    public string V8a { get; set; }
    public string V9 { get; set; }
    public string V9a { get; set; }
    public string V10 { get; set; }
    public int V10a { get; set; }
    public string V11 { get; set; }
    public string V11a { get; set; }
    public string V12 { get; set; }
    public string VulnerableOther { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string NINumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactDate { get; set; }
    public string CustDOB { get; set; }
    public double? PayAmount { get; set; }
    public bool ClearedFunds { get; set; }
    public double? PayAmount2 { get; set; }
    public bool ClearedFunds2 { get; set; }
    public int PayMethod { get; set; }
    public string ReceiptNo { get; set; }
    public double? DirectPayAmount { get; set; }
    public bool COT { get; set; }
    public string TitleCode { get; set; }
    public string OtherTitle { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitials { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string COTProofType { get; set; }
    public string COTDate { get; set; }
    public string PropRespMtrRead { get; set; }
    public string PropRespMtrBRead { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd1 { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd2 { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd3 { get; set; }
    public string PrevAdd4 { get; set; }
    public string PrevPostcode { get; set; }
    public string FwdName { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd1 { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd2 { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd3 { get; set; }
    public string FwdAdd4 { get; set; }
    public string FwdPostcode { get; set; }
    public bool PayArranged { get; set; }
    public string PayStartDate { get; set; }
    public double? PayArrAmount { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public string PayArrDetail { get; set; }
    public bool PPMAgreed { get; set; }
    public string PPMBookedDate { get; set; }
    public string PPMHHBookedTime { get; set; }
    public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
    public double? RecoveryRate { get; set; }
    public string PPMApptComments { get; set; }
    public bool PPMArranged { get; set; }
    public string PPMAppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public string PPMDetail { get; set; }
    public string AuthCode { get; set; }
    public string DateOfLeaving { get; set; }
    public string VacantPropComments { get; set; }
    public string CustComplaintCode { get; set; }
    public string DisputeComments { get; set; }
    public string IncidentDets { get; set; }
    public string PDVComments { get; set; }
    public bool Dissatisfaction { get; set; }
    public string DissatisfactionComments { get; set; }
    public bool HealthSafety { get; set; }
    public string ContactCode { get; set; }
    public string WhoSpokenTo { get; set; }
    public string HealthSafetyComments { get; set; }
    public string InfoNotes { get; set; }
    public bool EnergyTrust { get; set; }
    public string EnergyTrustComments { get; set; }
    public string VisitDate1 { get; set; }
    public string VisitTime { get; set; }
    public string VisitDate2 { get; set; }
    public string VisitTime2 { get; set; }
    public string ClientComments { get; set; }
    public string PDVNote { get; set; }

     public virtual List<SqlParameter> GetCommandParameters()
     {
         return new List<SqlParameter>
         {
             new SqlParameter("@CaseID", CaseID),
             new SqlParameter("@PDVTimestamp", Timestamp),
             new SqlParameter("@CustContactTel", CustContactTel),
             new SqlParameter("@CustMobileTel", CustMobileTel),
             new SqlParameter("@PropertyType", PropertyType),
             new SqlParameter("@PremisesStatus", PremisesStatus),
             new SqlParameter("@LockType", LockType),
             new SqlParameter("@AccessInfo", AccessInfo),
             new SqlParameter("@V1", V1),
             new SqlParameter("@V2", V2),
             new SqlParameter("@V2a", V2a),
             new SqlParameter("@V3", V3),
             new SqlParameter("@V4", V4),
             new SqlParameter("@V4a", V4a),
             new SqlParameter("@V5", V5),
             new SqlParameter("@V6", V6),
             new SqlParameter("@V7", V7),
             new SqlParameter("V7a", V7a),
             new SqlParameter("@V8", V8),
             new SqlParameter("@V8a", V8a),
             new SqlParameter("@V9", V9),
             new SqlParameter("@V9a", V9a),
             new SqlParameter("@V10", V10),
             new SqlParameter("@V10a", V10a),
             new SqlParameter("@V11", V11),
             new SqlParameter("@V11a", V11a),
             new SqlParameter("@V12", V12),
             new SqlParameter("@VulnerableOther", VulnerableOther),
             new SqlParameter("@ContactType", ContactType),
             new SqlParameter("@NINumber", NINumber),
             new SqlParameter("@CustDOB", ContactDate),
             new SqlParameter("@ContactDate", CustDOB),
             new SqlParameter("@PayAmount", PayAmount),
             new SqlParameter("@ClearedFunds", ClearedFunds),
             new SqlParameter("@PayAmount2", PayAmount2),
             new SqlParameter("@ClearedFunds2", ClearedFunds2),
             new SqlParameter("@PayMethod", PayMethod),
             new SqlParameter("@ReceiptNo", ReceiptNo),
             new SqlParameter("@DirectPayAmount", DirectPayAmount),
             new SqlParameter("@COT", COT),
             new SqlParameter("@TitleCode", TitleCode),
             new SqlParameter("@OtherTitle", OtherTitle),
             new SqlParameter("@FirstName", FirstName),
             new SqlParameter("@MiddleInitials", MiddleInitials),
             new SqlParameter("@SurName", SurName),
             new SqlParameter("@COTProofType", COTProofType),
             new SqlParameter("@COTDate", COTDate),
             new SqlParameter("@PropRespMtrRead", PropRespMtrRead),
             new SqlParameter("@PropRespMtrBRead", PropRespMtrBRead),
             new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd1", PrevAdd1),
             new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd2", PrevAdd2),
             new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd3", PrevAdd3),
             new SqlParameter("@PrevAdd4", PrevAdd4),
             new SqlParameter("@PrevPostcode", PrevPostcode),
             new SqlParameter("@FwdName", FwdName),
             new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd1", FwdAdd1),
             new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd2", FwdAdd2),
             new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd3", FwdAdd3),
             new SqlParameter("@FwdAdd4", FwdAdd4),
             new SqlParameter("@FwdPostcode", FwdPostcode),
             new SqlParameter("@PayArranged", PayArranged),
             new SqlParameter("@PayStartDate", PayStartDate),
             new SqlParameter("@PayArrAmount", PayArrAmount),
             new SqlParameter("@Frequency", Frequency),
             new SqlParameter("@PayArrDetail", PayArrDetail),
             new SqlParameter("@PPMAgreed", PPMAgreed),
             new SqlParameter("@PPMBookedDate", PPMBookedDate),
             new SqlParameter("@PPMHHBookedTime", PPMHHBookedTime),
             new SqlParameter("@EmploymentStatus", EmploymentStatus),
             new SqlParameter("@RecoveryRate", RecoveryRate),
             new SqlParameter("@PPMApptComments", PPMApptComments),
             new SqlParameter("@PPMArranged", PPMArranged),
             new SqlParameter("@PPMAppointmentDate", PPMAppointmentDate),
             new SqlParameter("@PPMDetail", PPMDetail),
             new SqlParameter("@AuthCode", AuthCode),
             new SqlParameter("@DateOfLeaving", DateOfLeaving),
             new SqlParameter("@VacantPropComments", VacantPropComments),
             new SqlParameter("@CustComplaintCode", CustComplaintCode),
             new SqlParameter("@DisputeComments", DisputeComments),
             new SqlParameter("@IncidentDets", IncidentDets),
             new SqlParameter("@PDVComments", PDVComments),
             new SqlParameter("@Dissatisfaction", Dissatisfaction),
             new SqlParameter("@DissatisfactionComments", DissatisfactionComments),
             new SqlParameter("@HealthSafety", HealthSafety),
             new SqlParameter("@Contact_Code", ContactCode),
             new SqlParameter("@WhoSpokenTo", WhoSpokenTo),
             new SqlParameter("@HealthSafetyComments", HealthSafetyComments),
             new SqlParameter("@InfoNotes", InfoNotes),
             new SqlParameter("@EnergyTrust", EnergyTrust),
             new SqlParameter("@EnergyTrustComments", EnergyTrustComments),
             new SqlParameter("@VisitDate1", VisitDate1),
             new SqlParameter("@VisitTime", VisitTime),
             new SqlParameter("@VisitDate2", VisitDate2),
             new SqlParameter("@VisitTime2", VisitTime2)
         };
     }
}
```

Because PDVHH  inherits PDV, we want all of the parameters that apply to that class aswell as the new properties the we have. This way we only maintain a list in appropriate places.

```
public class PDVHH : PDV
{
    public string PDVResult { get; set; }
    public string SecPDVResult { get; set; }
    public string D2PrintDate { get; set; }
    public string RPDVResult { get; set; }
    public string RSecPDVResult { get; set; }

    public override List<SqlParameter> GetCommandParameters()
    {
        var rtnList = base.GetCommandParameters();

        rtnList.Add(new SqlParameter("@PDVResult", PDVResult));
        rtnList.Add(new SqlParameter("@SecPDVResult", SecPDVResult));
        rtnList.Add(new SqlParameter("@D2PrintDate", D2PrintDate));
        rtnList.Add(new SqlParameter("@RPDVResult", RPDVResult));
        rtnList.Add(new SqlParameter("@RSecPDVResult", RSecPDVResult));

        return rtnList;
    }
}
```

This makes your save code much more succinct.

```
public void SavePDV(PDV pdv)
{
    SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("prcUMUpdateDebtPDVDetails", CommandType.StoredProcedure, pdv.GetCommandParameters());
}

public void SavePDVHH(PDVHH pdv)
{
    SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("prcUMUpdateDebtPDVHHDetails", CommandType.StoredProcedure, pdv.GetCommandParameters());
}
```